# Measuring two sides of the triangle

Tags: geometry, contest-math, circles, triangles

PQR is an isosceles triangle where PQ = PR. X is point on the circumcircle of ΔPQR, such that it being in the opposite region of P with respect to QR. The normal drawn from the point P on XR intersects XR at point Y. (see figure)

[image: Diagram of problem]

If XY=12, then find the value of QX+RX.

Comment: can you plot a picture please?

Comment: If $X$ is diametrically opposite $P$, then $QX + RX = 24$. If $X$ is close to $Q$, then also $QX+RX = 24$.

Comment: There was no picture in the question?

Comment: @peterwhy can you explain in details please?

Comment: The configuration looks like [this](http://i.imgur.com/gb7az8v.png), right?

Comment: @eyeballfrog I also think so

Comment: @user447259 I'll add it into the OP then.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner will you try please? There is a picture.

Comment: Poor @user447259.  You can't always expect to get spoon-fed when you ask questions so very poorly.  Even by pinging the unreliable user who answers any/everything, you're sure to lose out here and there.  Some users will spoon feed, but they're usually after rep and could care less about your homework questions.  If you're into contest-math (given you've used that tag in you two questions thus far), who's going to be there to hold your hand and spoon feed you while you're in a competition?

Comment: @amWhy Your opinion is right. but I am just a simple beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the diagram left of the line $PX$, and rotate the triangle $\triangle PQX$ about $P$ so that the image of $PQ$ coincide with $PR$. Let the rotated image of $X$ be $X'$.

Consider the cyclic quadrilateral $PQXR$,
$$\begin{align*}
\angle PQX + \angle PRX &= 180^\circ\\
\angle PRX' + \angle PRX &= 180^\circ\\
\end{align*}$$

So $XRX'$ is a straight line.

Also, $PX = PX'$, so $\triangle PXX'$ is isosceles.

$Y$ is the base of the altitude drawn from $P$ onto the (possibly extended) straight line $XR$, and is always between the base vertices $XX'$. So $Y$ is the midpoint of $XX'$, and

$$\begin{align*}
QX + XR &= RX' + XR\\
&= XX'\\
&= 2 XY\\
&= \underline{\underline{24}}
\end{align*}$$